# Setting up home wireless network with two separate modems/routers, not connected via ethernet

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I have two active cable jacks on either end of my house. I would like to make one wireless network that allows both of the modem/routers to be on the same wireless network so I have coverage throughout my house. It is not possible for me to connect the two routers via an Ethernet cable. Right now, one of the wireless routers is the combined modem/router that was provided by the cable company. The other cable jack has a modem that is then connected to an AirPort Express. Currently they are configured to operate as two completely separate wireless networks but I would like to combine them into one large network without having to connect the two routers via an Ethernet cable. Is this possible? All of my devices are wireless and none of them are connected to either router via an Ethernet cable. I do not have a desktop. Thank you.

Comment: By cable jack do you mean coaxial or ethernet?

Comment: What is on the other side of the 2 "cables" ? If it's your phone company, it might be hard since you can't have 2 broadband entry point . You must have only one than you share.
On the other side you may be able to use your AirPort Express as a wireless repeater.

Comment: Both the cables go back to the cable box on the outside of the house where there is a 3 way splitter. One for my TV, one for one modem and one for the other modem. Then a single cable goes back to the telephone pole behind my house.

Comment: By cable jack I mean coaxial, not ethernet. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because they are on coax, you won't have an easy time finding off the shelf hardware that will join the two networks together. If I am correct in assuming you have a modem provided by the ISP attached on each end of the house, then you are probably getting 2 different IP addresses from your ISP. This means they are essentially 2 different network connections.  A really long Ethernet cable is probably your best bet.

[Either that or set up wireless repeating on the AirPort Express.](https://www.google.ca/search?q=how%20to%20set%20up%20wireless%20repeating%20on%20an%20airport%20express)